# Rails - method put input not sent with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, put

When updating an object, we should `:method => :put` to override the `post` in the form as the following:

```
<%= simple_form_for @task, :url => update_task_url, :method => :put do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit 'Update Task'%>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', tasks_path %>
```

In the controller before making the request, I tried to render the params to check everything is correct as follow:

```
render text: tasks_params
uri = URI.parse("http://localhost/tasks/public/api/tasks/"+params[:id])
response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, task_params)
render text: response.body
```

but I get the following without the `_method` attribute:

```
{"name"=>"Task#1", "description"=>"lorem ipsum"}
```

and as a result the request is not successful on the server side. 
What am I missing here exactly?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, would you like to have the http method used in your params ?

Comment: I want to make a put request to the api

Comment: did you put a breakpoint in your `edit` method in the `TasksController` ?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more? I am still not familiar with RoR

Answer (score 0):

You should post to the desired controller action like so

```
<%= simple_form_for @task, :url => update_task_url, :method => :post do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_notification %>

      <div class="form-inputs">
        <%= f.input :name %>
        <%= f.input :description %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-actions">
          <%= f.submit 'Update Task'%>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

I would add a debugger break point in the `update` action in your `TasksController` just to make sure you are hitting the right route.

Comment: I am hitting the right route but the request to the link is not successful :/

Comment: what do you mean by "the request to the link" ?

Comment: The link is the API url specified in the uri field.